DRF Given token not valid for any token type
I am creating a simple DRF app and I have problems configuring JWT.
My main view looks like this:
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [filters.SearchFilter]
    filterset_fields = ["category"]
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        category = self.request.query_params.get("category", None)
        if category:
            queryset = queryset.filter(category=category)
        return queryset

My urls like this:
urlpatterns = [
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
    path("product-manager/", include("product_manager.urls")),
    path("", TokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair')
]

Now when I enter the index path and provide username and password in payload I get access and refresh tokens. I copy access token and put in into Authorization section in Postman in JWT Bearer while trying to access my ProductViewSet and I get
{
    "detail": "Given token not valid for any token type",
    "code": "token_not_valid",
    "messages": [
        {
            "token_class": "AccessToken",
            "token_type": "access",
            "message": "Token is invalid or expired"
        }
    ]
}

My settings:
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": (
        "rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication"
    ),
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 5,
}


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "product_manager",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework_simplejwt",
]

Chat GPT tells me debug the view, but when I try it, the debugger only stops on the breakpoint on the setup, but not when I try to access the endpoints linked to this view. Please help
